# Problem with calculating the total cell values

Tags: raster, arcpy, numpy

> > > aa= arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray("water_depth")
> > >
> > > sum = numpy.sum(aa)
> > >       print sum
> > >       -2933737

Why I am getting negative values ? In my raster there is no any negative depth.

Comment: How are your NoData values encoded?

Comment: How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: To find out your NoData value, right click the raster in the ArcMap table of contents, select Properties... click the Source tab and scroll down to find NoData value (it's in the Raster Information group).

Answer (score 5):

You could use a masked array like this:

```
#Assuming your NoData value is −32768
aa=numpy.ma.MaskedArray(arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray("water_depth"))
aa.mask=(aa==-32768)

#OR

#Explicitly set the nodata value
aa=numpy.ma.MaskedArray(arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray("water_depth",nodata_to_value=-999))
aa.mask=(aa==-999)

#OR

#Or just mask anything negative
aa=numpy.ma.MaskedArray(arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray("water_depth"))
aa.mask=(aa<0)

sum = aa.sum()

print sum
```

It might be a an integer overflow problem as @whuber suggests if the sum is greater than the bounds of a signed 32bit integer (numpy will cast smaller datatypes to bigger if required when summing, but won't cast int32 to int64 automatically). Consider the following code:

```
a=numpy.array([2**(16-1)-1,2**(16-1)-1],dtype=numpy.int16) # signed 16bit int (-32768:32767)
b=numpy.array([2**(32-1)-1,2**(32-1)-1],dtype=numpy.int32) # signed 32bit int (-2147483648:2147483647)

print a
print b
#  Prints:
# [32767 32767]
# [2147483647 2147483647]

# make them overflow
print a+1
print b+1
#  Prints:
# [-32768 -32768]
# [-2147483648 -2147483648]

print a.sum()
print (a.sum()).dtype # automatically cast to int32
# Prints:
# 65534
# int32

print b.sum()           # int32 overflows
print (b.sum()).dtype   # instead of being cast to int64
# Prints:
# -2
# int32

print b.astype(numpy.int64).sum() # explicitly cast to int64
# Prints:
# 4294967294
```

Comment: There's also a `nodata_to_value` parameter in [the `RasterToNumPyArray` function](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000023000000). This way you wouldn't need to look up the NoData value every time.

Comment: (+1) *IF* the problem is a negative code for NoData, then--because the OP asserts there should be no negative values in the raster--it would be more reliable to mask out all negative values.  But there are other potential causes of this problem, such as overflow of signed integer addition.

Comment: @dmahr thanks, I've incorporated your comments in the  answer